# Regex doesn't match \n in Python

Tags: python, regex, newline

I am using the following regex to extract email from message.

`Hi Helpdesk, I'm reaching out to you to ask for help about an accident I had. Is this the correct contact for accidental damages?\nTommaso Massari\nData Scientist\ntommaso_massari@gmail.com`

My code:

```
from_email = str(re.findall('\s*[a-zA-Z]*.*\s*[\\n]([a-zA-Z]*.*[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})',firstrow['message']))
```

It doesn't return anything in Python.

Expected output: `tommaso_massari@gmail.com`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're looking for the `DOTALL` flag.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL

Also, sometimes the `MULTILINE` flag
is relevant for text containing newlines.